# PHP to include all files from root directory (like a CMS)

Tags: php, root

I need to create subfolders with their own index.php files inside them for my pages.  When I include the header and footer files in the root directory, however, the site breaks because the header file is looking for all the CSS and JavaScript files in the current directory.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use relative paths in the include, and `..` to go up a directory.

```
include('../functions.php');
```

This will include functions.php from the parent folder.  If it were 2 folders deep, it would be `../../functions.php`

This is the most common way of including things in other folders, actually providing a relative yet direct path.  Using the parsers include_path can work but is not as portable.

**Just a quick comparison of the execution plan of both approaches:**

Using `include('../functions.php');`:

Check parent folder, open functions.php

Using include_path, lets say only 3 paths in list, and `include('functions.php');`

Check current folder, file does not exist

Check first path in include_path, file does not exist

Check second path in include_path, file does not exist

Check third path in include_path, open functions.php

Then you have to hope that someone doesn't put a functions.php in one of those other included paths...

Comment: How is `include_path` less portable?

Comment: @cHao Most hosting places don't let you update php.ini, as the most obvious example.

Comment: @cHao For two, if you're moving it to an environment with other existing projects you could run in to conflicts (especially if they are doing the same thing.)

Comment: @Fosco: `ini_set('include_path', dirname(__FILE__).PATH_SEPARATOR.ini_get('include_path'));`.  Works regardless of access to php.ini, regardless of OS...and doesn't stomp all over the include path.

Comment: @cHao I expected that answer and almost posted a pre-emptive response.  You know that's only going to work on the current page and would have to be included on every page right?  Every page would have to get and set the current executions include path, and the server would have to follow the include path to find files... What would make you think that is better than explicitly stating you want the parent folder with `..`?  Hence my original point, your answer works (without modifying every page), but it's not standard and not as portable.

Comment: there's also `dirname(__DIR__)` to go up a dir, for absolute paths, if you don't prefer relative paths. (edit: bite me, markdown.)

Comment: @Fosco: What makes it better is that multiple levels of includes resolve correctly.  If i have a script `dir1/dir2/dir3/test.php` that includes `../test.php`, which includes `../test.php`, PHP segfaults on the Linux box i just tested on.  Meanwhile, if i include `dir1/dir2/test.php`, which includes `dir1/test.php`, the ambiguity is resolved.

Comment: @Fosco: Also, `../../../include.php` is not nearly as obvious as `dirname/include.php`.

Comment: @cHao I'm pretty sure you accidentally put it into a circular reference.  As specified there's nothing technically wrong with the nested dir1/dir2/dir3 includes you mentioned, though the merits of that design could be questioned.

Comment: @cHao lol, you just made the wrong comparison for your solution... `../../../include.php` is a lot more obvious than `include.php` (and needing to check the include_path to find out where that might be.)

Comment: @Fosco: Yeah, i personally don't like having include files in the root of the site, for that reason among others.  Or if i do, i get rid of the old include_path (so it only contains the document root, and maybe `.`).  But no, it's not more obvious...it's just more explicit.

Comment: @Fosco:  And LOL, it wasn't me that accidentally created the circular reference.  PHP did that, because of some oddness in how it does relative includes.  It likes to base them on the location of the original script, which likes to mess up when your included files include other files via relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

For the server side, add the root to your `include_path` setting (or, if you don't intend to include from anywhere else, replace the `include_path` with the root), and you'll be able to refer to the files in it from anywhere.

Client-side, you'd use the `<base>` tag to tell a browser where URLs start from (ie: where relative URLs end up pointing to).  You only really need this if you're linking the CSS and JS rather than including them, but that's the more common scenario.  (You'd usually include PHP, and link CSS/JS.)